# How can I print in binary mode in GDB?

Tags: gdb

I tried `b`, but it seems not to work:

```
(gdb) p/b 0x0000000000400398
Size letters are meaningless in "print" command.
```

Is there such a switch?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You need the `/t` switch which works with both `p` and `x`:

```
(gdb) p /t 0x0000000000400398
$1 = 10000000000001110011000
```

See `help x` for more info on the FMT (format) switches.

Comment: @PaulR but the size letters are meaningless in "print" command, so it certainly ought to be the *b* ;)

Comment: As per manual, Print as integer in binary. The letter `t' stands for "two". (2)

Comment: The `t` switch isn't a `size` switch but a `format` switch. That's why gdb will not warn you about `size letters` being `meaningless`. ;-)

Comment: No space when using lldb:
```(lldb) p/t 0x0000000000400398
(int) $0 = 0b00000000010000000000001110011000```

Answer (score 7):

`x/4tb  0x0000000000400398` will let you analyze the memory address with binary values.